# Deserializing json without key name

Tags: c#, json

i have json answer, like this, without key names, only values

```
[
  [
    1645724820000,
    "35893.01000000",
    "35898.38000000",
    "35850.01000000",
    "35876.07000000",
    "10.19782000",
    1645724879999,
    "365831.59479120",
    335,
    "2.90744000",
    "104298.60366850",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1645724880000,
    "35876.79000000",
    "35910.93000000",
    "35864.93000000",
    "35910.93000000",
    "8.15710000",
    1645724939999,
    "292722.41648950",
    326,
    "3.18438000",
    "114275.09871200",
    "0"
  ]
]
```

i try deserializing with Newtonsoft, next C# code

```
    public class Root
            {
                public List<List<String>> MyArray { get; set; }
            } 
//Root Pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Data2Json);
```

but it does't work, i'm begginer programmer, help pls, how i can deserializing it json. I guess it needs to be deserialized into some kind of array or list of values since there are no key names, but I don't know how, Google doesn't help anymore

Comment: *but it does't work* - because your json array is not inside a root object. Had your json looked like `{"MyArray":[[1645724820000, ...` then sure..

Comment: @CaiusJard don't we need a canonical at this stage for these never-ending questions about incorrectly deserializing json in c#?

Comment: I don't doubt there are some candidates already, though annoyingly the 999+ accepted answer is from 2010 and starts `JavaScriptSerializer jss = new ...`. Perhaps we should expand the scope and make a "how to get data from an API and deserialize it" so some OpenAPI/Swagger advice and "how to use HttpClient without destabilizing your software" can be chucked in too. But then would it become "too broad" ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

```
List<List<string>> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(json);
```